# What custom jQuery events does docassemble trigger?

Tags: docassemble

I was trying to figure out if the 'Help' buttons triggered anything special that I could listen for to trigger my own function. I knew there was `daPageLoad` and wondered what others exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docassemble triggers only one custom event and that is `daPageLoad`.

Bonus info: The 'Help' button does not trigger any special events. The `section`s do have the `tab-pane` class, but I can't detect any [tab pane events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events) going on and the 'Help' button does not have the appropriate attributes on it to control the tabs.

Right now I'm solving my js problem by listening for a 'click tap' whenever a `button` or `a` is pressed (the help button is actually a link under the hood).